# How to use typeid to get the type name which defined use typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, typeid

Here is my problem:

I defined a new type and used the new type to declare a variable:

```
typedef int new_type;
new_type value;
```

I need somehow get the new_type as a string back using typeid, but if I use:

```
typeid(value)
```

It will return int, instead of new_type.

Is there a way to get new_type as a string back?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure, but it seems to me that there isn't a way to do this using `typeid`. Probably preprocessor's stringize would suit you?

Comment: @lisyarus CPP stringize wouldn't help, since the point is to use `typeid(value)` (with the variable!).

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want to solve this way? May be there are better approaches instead of using `typeid()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typedef`'s aren't their *own types*. Think of it as an alias for the original type.

> *"Is there a way to get new_type as a string back?"*

Since it isn't a *real type* of it's own, no.

---

Remember that the `typeid()` intrinsic has **`id`** in it's name, that means it should always return the **same identifier** for the (effectively) same types.

The only way I can think of to achieve what you want, is creating your own wrapper `class`/`struct` that behaves exactly like an `int`. But I doubt it's worth the efforts.